# Verify sup, max, min, inf for $\{\frac{n+3}{n}\;:\;n \in \mathbb N\}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I think I'm finally starting to understand this and wanted to check that I answered the following correctly:

$\{\frac{n+3}{n}\;:\;n \in \mathbb N\}$

inf: 1

min: 4

sup: DNE

max: DNE

Comment: Inf is correct. Min does not exist. Sup and max is $4$.

Comment: I know that this is already answered, but what doers DNE mean?

Comment: @IrregularUser Does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $n\mapsto(n+3)/n$ is decreasing. Moreover, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n+3)/n=1$. Therefore, $\inf=1$.

For the same reasons, there is no $\min$. Indeed, suppose the minimum is attained at $n$. However, letting $m=n+1$, $(m+3)/m<(n+3)/n$, contradicting that $n$ is the point at which the minimum is attained.

Can you figure out the $\sup$/$\max$ case?

---

**Addendum:** These definitions might be of help. In the following,  $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary and nonempty.

> The *minimum* of $S$ is an element $x\in S$ such that for all $s\in S$, $x\leq s$.

An infimum is defined differently. First, let's introduce the following:

> A *lower bound* of $S$ is a number $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (this is the
>   important part, $x$ is **not** necessarily restricted to be in $S$!)
>   such that for all $s\in S$, $x\leq s$.

Now we can define infimum:

> An *infimum* of $S$ is a lower bound $x$ of $S$ such that for all
>   other lower bounds $x$ of $S$, $y\geq x$.

Maximums and supremums are defined similarly.

Comment: I get it, $1$ is the smallest $n \in \mathbb N$ that can produce the largest number in the set.  So when $n=1$ the supremum $4$ and the max is $4$

Comment: It has nothing to do with $1$ being small; it has to do with $4$ being the largest number in the set and all other numbers being smaller than it (recall the decreasing property). I think you are on the right path.

Comment: @free_mind: I have added some definitions that you might find helpful.

Comment: I asked a question about the definitions yesterday and yours is BY FAR the easiest to understand.  Thank you!